# Scrapy Iterate start_requests from response

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import itertools

class MySpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
        def start_requests(self):
            makes_list_all = []
            for page, make in itertools.product(range(1,21), makes_list_all):
                yield self.make_requests_from_url('https://www.example.com/?page={page}&mmm={make}||'.format(page=page, make=make))


/* Do something */
```

Here I response all IDs, and want to set it as `makes_list_all` list

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
        html = Selector(response)
        item = ItemnameItem()
        products = html.xpath('//body')
        items = []
        for product in products:
            item = ItemnameItem()
#Get IDs
            try:
                ids_step_one = r'"searchFilters":{"makes":\[(.*?)}]'
                ids_step_two = r'{"id":(.*?),"name":"'
                current_page_ids = product.xpath('//script[@id="initial-state"]')[0].re(ids_step_one)[0]
                current_page_ids = re.findall(ids_step_two, current_page_ids)
                print ('current_page_ids :')
                print (current_page_ids) #[u'9', u'13', u'29', u'47', u'16338', u'52', u'54', u'57', u'60', u'64', u'65', u'74']
                try:
                    print ('ok')
                except IndexError:
                    print ('-= NOT AVAILABLE =-')
                    current_page_ids = 'null'
            except IndexError:
                print ('-= IndexError =-')
                current_page_ids = ''
                pass
            except KeyError:
                print ('-= KeyError =-')
                current_page_ids = ''
                pass
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Example:

current_page_ids:

```
[u'9', u'13', u'29', u'47', u'16338', u'52', u'54', u'57', u'60', u'64', u'65', u'74']
```

My question is: How to add this IDs to generare `start_requests` ?

I need to append `current_page_ids` to `makes_list_all`, to start parse this urls:

1. example.com/?page=1&mmm=9,
2. example.com/?page=1&mmm=13, etc.. (from list)
3. example.com/?page=2&mmm=9,
4. example.com/?page=2&mmm=13 ...

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to append `current_page_ids` to `makes_list_all` or use `itertools.product(range(1, 21), current_page_ids)`. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: @StefanGolubović
I want use `current_page_ids` as `makes_list_all`, to generate links from this list.

Comment: Can you add `current_page_ids` list to your code example?

Comment: @StefanGolubović
I have `current_page_ids`, and want to generate from this IDs URL like at bottom of post, Thanks for you response

Comment: @StefanGolubović
Something like this: 
`makes_list_all = ['9', '13', '29', '47', '16338', '52', '54', '57', '60', '64', '65', '74']`

On next response page, i need next page IDs

Comment: Well, even with more code provided, I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around on how to pass `current_page_ids` from `parse_item` method to `start_requests` method.